# Ubuntu 14.04 can't find my wireless network

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't connect to the router (which is only 2m away).

My smartphone (Android) has connection to it. When I switch to Windows 7 I have connection to my WiFi.

When I type `sudo iwlist wlan0 s | grep SSID` into Terminal I get a list of many wireless networks, except mine. Also it returns two networks without the name - is it weird?

`wlan0` is my one and only wireless card.

Command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` returns:

```
12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0012]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

**EDIT:** I ran Ubuntu 14.04 from USB drive (named Live-CD) and this version of Ubuntu detected my network! I think the difference between this 2 operating systems are drivers. So, how can I change drivers in my installed Ubuntu into this from Live-CD?

Comment: Were you use to connect to that said Wireless network before? and have you made any changes after? Also, have you by any chance, made your SSID hidden?

Comment: I don't understand the first question.

I haven't an access to the router, but when I tried to connect to it with my smartphone the network was visible. So, I think, network is visible right now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have updated my question

Comment: I was asking whether have you connected to the SSID before using the same PC before?

Comment: Yes, I have connected to other networks using this laptop and OS before and everything was good. Right now I'm trying to connect to the new network

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're following my comment. What I actually meant was whether you were able to connect to the said SSID using the computer which you cannot seem to connect? As in before the problem persists

Comment: I can connect with this problematic network using Win 7 installed on this laptop. Using Ubuntu 14.04 I can connect with other networks, but with this problematic network - I can't. My network application can't find this network, but it finds other networks.

Comment: Reposted from a comment by Orr22: *I'm having the same problem. Laptop does not show the wifi connection and two days ago worked fine. In the telephone and in the laptop the same wifi connections are seen, with the exception that in the laptop the house connection doesn't show.*

Comment: Do you think this problem can be cause by not-updated wifi drivers?